# Angular, cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList'

Tags: javascript, angular, intersection-observer

I'm trying to use intersection observer to add a class to some text after it passes a trigger point.

I confirmed that my observer was working when some of my text turned blue but some of my other texts that I want aren't turning blue.  My trigger point should turn anything I want blue but it's not able to see some of the elements for some reason.

My console reads:  `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')`

Stack: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzy8z7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title-big">
    <div class="text" #text>
      <span class="highlight">Trigger</span>
      <p>If font color is blue, trigger works for me</p>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="vertical-line"></div> -->

    <div class="work">If font color is blue, trigger works for me</div>
  </div>

  <div class="l-container" #choosePersonFade>
    <div class="b-game-card {{ info.chi }}" *ngFor="let info of list">
      <div class="name">
        {{ info.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const threshold = 0.7;
    const observer6 = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {

            entry.target.classList.add('activate');
            this.work.nativeElement.classList.add('activate'); //Doesn't work

            // this.jerry.nativeElement!.classList.add('activate'); Doesn't work
            // this.bob.nativeElement!.classList.add('activate'); Doesn't work
            // this.matt.nativeElement!.classList.add('activate'); Doesn't work
          }
        });
      },
      { threshold }
    );

    observer6.observe(this.text.nativeElement);
    // observer6.observe(this.choosePersonFade.nativeElement);
  }

  @ViewChild('text') text!: ElementRef;

  list = [
    {
      name: 'jerry',
    },
    {
      name: 'matt',
    },
    {
      name: 'bob',
    },
  ];

  get jerry() {
    return this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.jerry');
  }

  get matt() {
    return this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.matt');
  }

  get bob() {
    return this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.bob');
  }
  get work() {
    return this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.work');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here this.work represent DOM element.

```
this.work.classList.add('activate');
```